# How to get TLS/SSL with hetzner LB?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, hetzner-cloud

I have [Hetzner LB](https://github.com/hetznercloud/hcloud-cloud-controller-manager) and [bitnami Discourse app](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/discourse/README.md).

I don't know how to get SSL/TLS connection.

I guess connection should be next Hetzner LB -> (proxy)-> My ingress-> regular service for pod connection -> pod/backend

I guess ingress should be responsible for TLS/SSL.

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: I made a simple working [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78007316/9183844). Please take a look.